# How can I create a repeating set of stripes, just like in the American Flag

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pycharm

Hello fellow progammers. I am new to programming and I am looking for some help on a project creating an American flag through tkinter. This is really my first practice with it. My problem is actually creating the recurring stripes. My idea was to through my .pack() in a loop and let the program pack each stripe one after another (red then white). I use i % 2 == 0 to tell if i is even or odd. If i is even, then pack a red stripe in. If not, then a white stripe. When I run the code below, I only see one red stripe in a sea of white. Please show me the error of my ways.

My idea is to create the stripes then layer the sea of blue over the stripes, and then somehow fill the blue with '*' for stars. Bonus points if you could also point me in a good direction to that end as well.

Thank you for your time.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.geometry("500x300")
red_stripe = Label(window, bg= "red")
white_stripe = Label(window, bg= "white")

# sea_of_blue = Frame(window, bg= "blue", width= 220, height= 130)
for i in range(5):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        one.pack(fill=x)
    else:
        two.pack(fill=x)

# sea_of_blue.place(relx= 0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  Your posted code fails on undefined variables.  I don't see in here where you create multiple stripes; you keep overwriting the existing ones.

Comment: What is `x`, `one` and `two`. ? Did you mean `fill='x'`

Comment: tkinter is the wrong tool for this. Use an image editing module like Pillow.

Comment: @Novel - Why do you say that? It's fine as programming practice. Tkinter is a pretty capable framework.

Comment: @CoolCloud- Sorry that is actually my bad. one and two were the names of the variables that i was using in my IDE before I came to ask my question here. I changed the variables around so the reader could make more sense of it, but I missed these changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example 1:**
I declared the label inside the loop as follows, and it seems to work:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x300")

for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        Label(window, bg= "red",width=500).grid(row=i)
    else:
        Label(window, bg= "white",width=500).grid(row=i)

window.mainloop()
```

Notice that I'm defining the label inside the loop, so that new label gets created each time and gets placed at alternate position, while `range(10)`, limits it to 10 strips. Here I'm giving `width=100` just so that the label fills the whole window up.

**Example 2:**
If your not planning to re-use the label, *Example 1* is fine, else if you want to make some other use of it, then you have to assign a variable and `grid()` separately, like:

```
for i in range(5):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        first = Label(window, bg="red",width=500)
        first.grid(row=i)
    else:
        second = Label(window, bg="white",width=500)
        second.grid(row=i)
```

But this gives you control over the last respective labels only.

**Example 3:**
Or again, if you want individual control over the strips, then create a label and append it to a list and call the nth item of the list to get the nth label.

```
labels = []
for i in range(5):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        labels.append(Label(window, bg= "red",width=100))
        labels[i].grid(row=i)
    else:
        labels.append(Label(window, bg= "white",width=100))
        labels[i].grid(row=i)

Button(window,text='Click me',command=lambda:labels[3].config(bg='green')).grid(row=i+1,sticky='w')
```

Notice that when you click on the button the 4th label changes color, that is the 4th item in your list. So you can access each label like `labels[n]` where n is the row number of the required label starting from 0.

**Example 4:**
A very simplified and better example using ternary operator so as to get rid of the `if` statements:

```
labels = []
for i in range(5):
    bg = 'white' if i%2 else 'red'
    labels.append(Label(window, bg=bg,width=100))
    labels[i].grid(row=i)
```

Your second question however remains unclear and it is also better to just ask one question in one post.

Comment: You could use ternary operator `bg="white" if i%2 else "red"` and get rid of the `if...else`.

Comment: @HenryYik Ive never used ternary operators before, hope this is the correct way

Comment: @CoolCloud- Thank you for such an in-depth response. Really. It was a pleasure to wake up and see that my question was answered above and beyond what I expected!

Comment: @CoolCloud - Got it! Thanks again!